# How do I install a high intensity infrared heater and thermostat

Tags: wiring, hvac

I picked up an old Lambert L-40 high intensity infrared gas heater but it didn’t have a thermostat. I can’t find any info about this heater online and I am hoping someone on here can help.

I connected the heater to a natural gas line and power and can get the sparker to light the pilot but I can’t get the main burners to light. I assume that is because I do not have a thermostat calling for heat.

I have included pictures on this post so please let me know if anyone knows this heater or can tell me how to wire it and what kind of thermostat and transformer I need.

Thank you

[image: Control box]

[image: Heater Info]

[image: Internal of control box]

Answer (score 1):

Do not hook this to mains power.

Get yourself a 24VAC, 40VA transformer, which is common as dirt, $12, and widely used on conventional furnaces.  They typically mount either on the cover of a 4x4 square metal junction box, or in a 1/2" trade size knockout on the side of such a box.  Both these wiring methods put the mains power inside the metal junction box, and the 24VAC power on the outside.

- The transformer provides two 24V terminals: R and C.
- Your thermostat requires 3 wires: R, W and C.
- Your heater needs W and C.

The R wire should be red.  The W wire should be white.  The preferred color for C is blue, but that may not be practical in 2-3 wire cable.

This setup, which is mandatory for this heater, will allow you to use *almost* any thermostat on earth including smart 'stats like the Nest.

If you *ever* anticipate doing A/C or heat pump you want at least 6 wires in the cable to the thermostat.

Comment: Hi Harper, thank you for the answer but I’m still a little confused about wiring this heater. There is already a transformer attached to the outside of the control box with an off/on switch and wired into a 120 volt plug. The transformer has a blue and a yellow wire connected to the blue and white receptacles on the control box. There is nothing connected to the red receptacle on the control box.