# How do I connect a high intensity infrared heater and thermostat?

Tags: electrical, hvac

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkMto.jpg)Harper gave me a great answer on [how to connect my Lambert high intensity heater to a thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149499/how-do-i-install-a-high-intensity-infrared-heater-and-thermostat) in general but I have a follow up question and don’t know how to attach that to my original post so I am creating a new question.

My heater has a transformer connected to the control box and is running blue and yellow wires that attach to the blue and white connectors respectively on the control box. However I have an empty red wire connector on the control box which I assume is for the thermostat but I don’t know where to connect the thermostat’s white wire. Can anyone please help me with this question?  Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: This  probably could have been an amendment to the original question, since it wasn't resolved completely. Go that route instead if you prefer.

Comment: Isherwood, that is exactly what it is but I couldn’t figure out how to add to my original question. Should I have done it thru the “Comment” tab?

Comment: Nope. There's a handy 'edit' link right there in the post menu. :)

Comment: If you do that, close this one using the option in the same menu.

Comment: Can you post an up-close, top-down view of the control box?

Comment: Please let me know if this close up helps or if you need a different angle. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a close-up of the part of the ignition control cover that's currently hidden by the wires from the transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try connecting the thermostat red wire to the blue terminal and the thermostat white wire to the red terminal

From the labeling on the cover of your ignition module, connecting 24VAC power between 2 and GR will turn the *pilot* burner on, while connecting 24VAC power between 3 and GR will turn the *main* burner on.  So, if you connect the red (R) wire to your thermostat to the blue (2) terminal on the ignition module (aka the blue wire from the transformer), and the white (W) wire to your thermostat to the red (3) terminal on the ignition module, you should get the unit to fire up when the thermostat closes.

If your thermostat needs a blue (C) wire, it can be connected to the white (GR) terminal on the ignition module (aka the yellow wire from the transformer).

Comment: I connected a tstat at that only requires 2 wires as you described and things changed but there are still questions. When the tstat at is not calling for heat, the pilot puffs on and off but will not stay lit and short puffs of unlit gas come out of the burners at the same time. When the tstat calls for heat, the pilot light stops puffing and goes out and a constant stream of unlit gas comes out of the burners. I can manually light the gas at the burners which has fairly smooth 6-8” flames but it is not rushing out like a blowtorch and the ceramic stayed cold Also the sparker runs constantly.

Comment: @DaveS. -- sounds like the ignition control module is toasticles

Comment: I was afraid it would be something major like that. Sounds like it might be time to end this experiment and move on to a different solution to heat my garage. Thanks for all of your help and advice ThreePhaseEel.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been doing HVAC/R for many years. I found a product on Amazon that relieves the issues of running Wire for a tstat.

Nashone Digital Wireless Temperature Controller, Built in Temp Sensor Electric Thermostat Socket 3 Prong Plug LCD Display Heating Cooling Mode.

I've been using this same product for about 3 years. My customers love it. I actually have one in my shop running my infra-red heater as well. 
 This thermostat turns the 120v receptacle ON and OFF as it calls for heating. This same t-stat will work with a cooling system. When the stat calls for heat, it will turn the 120 volt outlet ON. this will allow the heater to turn on. When the stat is satisfied it will turn the outlet OFF. 
 Its a wireless system. works really well and saves time and money. No need to run wires. 
 NO I am not affiliated with this product in ANY way. there are many brands that can do the same thing. I found this on Amazon, and for the money, it does a great job. .
.   The cost is about $25 or so.

Comment: If i knew how to add photos, I would show you the set-up I have in my shop.

Comment: When editing a question, there's an "Add Picture" icon which looks like a couple of mountains; click it and follow the instructions. If that doesn't work, post the URL of the picture and someone will be along to edit it in.

Comment: How would the Nashone unit signal the main gas valve to open? Currently, when I power the unit on it allows the pilot to light but it is waiting for a signal from a thermostat to open the main valve.

Comment: @DaveS. -- can you post a photo of the ignition unit cover with the wires out of the way?

Comment: TherePhaseEel, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @DaveS. -- it is indeed, although you tried to edit it into Tech's answer instead of your question.  I caught that, grabbed the photo, and edited it into the question for you :)

Comment: Thank you, obviously I still don’t know how to use this tool correctly